A criterion for proving that an algebraic extension $E \subset F$ of fields is normal.
Let $K \subset F$ be fields such that $F$ is an algebraic extension of $K$, if for all elements $\alpha \in F$ there is a field $K \subset E \subset F$ such that $\alpha \in E$ and $E$ is normal over $K$ then $F$ is normal over $K$.
So my idea is this, let $f(x) \in K[x]$ be irreducible, with a root $\alpha \in F$ and WLOG assume that $f(x)$ is monic. I know that there is a field $E$ that is normal over $K$ and such that $K \subset E \subset F$
then $f(x)$ can be written as
$c(x-\beta_0)(x-\beta_1)\dots(x-\beta_n)$
where $c, \beta_i \in E$ and $\alpha = \beta_0$
Now, since $F$ is a field, it follows that $F[x]$ is a UFD, therefore we can write $f$ as
$f(x) = v g_1 \dots g_m $ where $v \in F$ and $g_i \in F[x]$ are irreducible polynomials, but since each polynomial
$ (x-\beta_i)$ is irreducible, this is also a factorization in $F[x]$ and therefore, up to a reordering of the factors, we have that $n =m$ and each
$g_i = d_i (x-\beta_i)$ therefore we can write $f \in F[x]$ as
$d(x-\beta_0)(x-\beta_1)\dots(x-\beta_n) $ with $d = c d_1 \dots d_n \in F$ so $f$ splits completely in $F$.
Is this proof correct? I think it's correct but I'd like to have confirmation, because I never used that $F$ is an algebraic extension. Also, is there a simpler proof?

I think it is correct but overcomplicated. You may directly say that "$c(x-\beta_0)(x-\beta_1)\dots(x-\beta_n)$ is also a factorization in $F[x]$, i.e. polynomial in $K{x}$ with one root in $F$ factorizes completely into monic factor in $F[x]$."

Your third paragraph don’t establish anything. Normal extension is by definition algebraic extension. So each $u\in F$ is algebraic over $K$, since $u\in E$ is algebraic over $K$. I would write proof in following way:
Let $f\in K[x]$ be irreducible polynomial such that $f(u)=0$ for some $u\in F$. By hypothesis, $u\in E$ is normal over $K$, so $f$ split over $E$. In particular, $f$ split over $F$. Thus $F$ is normal over $K$.
